# Replay events and ingest them in AWS Timestream

Tags: time-series, amazon-timestream

I can't ingest records into AWS Timestream if timestamp is out of the window of Memory Store. Thus, I can't implement functionality where I replay messages, process and ingest them if there is some issue. Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is not a way to ingest records that are outside of the memory store retention window. Would you be able to create a table with a memory store retention window large enough for the window that you expect to be correcting data?